# Is it possible in a dict?- creating a dict and adding each key by increment

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I'm trying to take some selective values from a dict which is inside another dict.

```
new_list = {}

for x in name_list:
    y =name_list[x]
    num =0  
    for key, value in y.items():
        if value == 'a_given_string_from_key':
            print(name_list[x])
            num= num+1
            new_list.update(num ,name_list[x])
```

But it looks not possible. How to resolve this?

Input:

```
name_list = {
      1 : {'_name' :'gilchrist','Team_name' : 'australia'},
      2 : {'_name' :'dhoni','Team_name' : 'india'},
      3 : {'_name' :'prior','Team_name' : 'england'},
      4 : {'_name' :'rishab','Team_name' : 'india'}, 
      5 : {'_name' :'rahul','Team_name' : 'india'}                           
 }
```

Expected otput:

```
new_list = {
      1 : {'_name' :'dhoni','Team_name' : 'india'},
      2 : {'_name' :'rishab','Team_name' : 'india'}, 
      3 : {'_name' :'rahul','Team_name' : 'india'} 
      }
```

I need those `new_list` keys incrementally.

Comment: Can you update your question and add there sample input and expected output?

Comment: @AndrejKesely.u can now check it

Comment: You named your variable `new_list`, but made it a dictionary. It seems you actually want a list, so why don't you just use a list instead?

Comment: @mkrieger1 i want the values only inside a dict..that was my mistake...i have edited now..check it

Comment: You have just removed the variable definition, so now the code in the question won't even run anymore. But still, why don't you use a list instead of a dictionary? Lists are indexed by incrementing integers by definition.

Comment: @mkrieger1 i need those specifed dict's in my new dict for further validations...

Comment: no error messages @mkrieger1... i'm trying to do this because i needs the specific items with their full of key and values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just replace

```
new_list.update(num ,name_list[x])
```

by

```
new_list[num] = name_list[x]
```

this seems to do what you want.

The `update` method can be used to change multiple items in a dictionary at once, by taking them from another dictionary.

But you simply want to insert one item at a time into the dictionary.

---

The name `new_list` and the fact that you want to use incrementing integers as keys suggests that you actually want `new_list` to be a list, not a dictionary. You would change the code to this:

```
new_list = []

for y in name_list.values():
    for value in y.values():
        if value == 'a_given_string_from_key':
            new_list.append(y)
            break
```

The result should be something like

```
new_list = [
    {'_name' :'dhoni','Team_name' : 'india'},
    {'_name' :'rishab','Team_name' : 'india'}, 
    {'_name' :'rahul','Team_name' : 'india'} 
]

# new_list[0] --> {'_name' :'dhoni','Team_name' : 'india'}
# new_list[1] --> {'_name' :'rishab','Team_name' : 'india'}
# etc.
```

I've made some other small improvements which I'll leave for you to figure out.